# 5G NR PUCCH format-0

Tags: 5g

In 5G-NR PUCCH format-0, for multiplexing of UE's (i.e., UE's sharing the same RB for resource allocation) which are sending the same/different HARQ's or SR should have different initial cyclic shift(m0) values or can all UE's which are gonna multiplex in same RB(Resource Block) have same m0 value?